# Applying logics to this simple Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I am stuck trying to build a *Tic Tac Toe* game in JavaScript. I am having trouble writing the logic for the winning condition. There are other parts of the program that work fine.

---

###### Bellow is the code I have written:

```js
// Wrong Code..?

const winning = () => {
  const winning = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i <= winning.length; i++) {
    const condition = winning[i];
    let a = spaces[condition[0]];
    let b = spaces[condition[1]];
    let c = spaces[condition[2]];
    if (a === "" || b === "" || c === "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      roundWon = true;
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: um, what logic?

Comment: Explain what is the **current** behavior of the program (when you click button X in the program, it prints out Y), and what is the **expected** behavior (should print out Z instead). Best with a stack snippet.

Comment: `i <= winning.length` is your first bug.  Should definitely be `i < winning.length`

Comment: First of all, logic is already plural, so don't use the word Logics, secondly, you should capitalize the first letter of each sentence, and add a period to the end of each sentence as well. These suggestions will help make your question & comments more readable, easier to understand, and will improve your chances of receiving the solution you seek. Now as far as the actual question goes: You don't explain what the problem is, you don't include any debugging info, and you don't explain what it is your trying to do. Before you repeat yourself to me, know that

Comment: "I can't do", or "I can't figure out",  is not a good enough explanation of what it is you are asking for. You need to ask, not for a program to write correctly, but for a solution to a well-defined issue. You mention that you cannot get the winning logic to work, but you don't explain what the winning logic, that you are trying to write, is. You should have some idea of what it is, as your attempting to develop it. You also do not specify a particular problem, something that says, "Hey I am trying to write this logic, however, I keep getting this error.

Comment: Does anyone know what could cause this issue, or how to fix it?". The pseudo-line I wrote demonstrates the proper format that should be used, and since your writing is a very valid program, you are able to ask questions in such a way. Learning how to ask on, bot just S.O., but all Q&A's is a skill set, and it takes a while to get good at. I hope you don't take this as me being a rude mean guy, because it took me quite long to write this, in hopes that I will help you, help make the Stack Overflow community better/.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that in your `handleClick` function you try to check if a space at the position is still empty, if so set it to the `currentPlayer` which is either `X` or `O`, but this won't work because you

1. use the `id` propertie of the target which was clicked on which doesn't return the index but the `id` of that element, and
2. while you fill your `spaces` array with `null`, in you `playerWon` function you check for empty string. And
3. besides that, there are a few things here and there that you could do better.

First add some values to the spaces array (`undefined` is the best choice here in my opinion, also we are going to use `let` here so we can redefine the variable for reset). Let your `reset` function be an actual reset function.:

```
let spaces = [
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined
]
```

To fix the the index problem, so you can change the value of the spaces array at the associated cell index, you can pass the `handleClick` function an index argument when you iterate over all the cells and add a click EventListener to them.

```
cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
  cell.addEventListener("click", () => handleClick(e, index));
});
```

Your `handleClick` function would then look like this:

```
function handleClick(e, i) {
  if (spaces[i] == undefined) {
    spaces[i] = currentPlayer;
    e.target.innerText = currentPlayer;

    if (playerWon()) {
      playText.innerText = `${currentPlayer} has won!`;
      restart();
      return;
    }
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === OPlayer ? XPlayer : OPlayer;
  }
}
```

In the restart function, instead of iterating over all the values in the `spaces` array, just redefine it:

```
spaces = [
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined, 
  undefined
]
```

You also still have to return something from the playerWon function and instead of checking for an empty string, you should now check for `undefined`.

```
function playerWon() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winning.length; i++) {
    const condition = winning[i];
    let a = spaces[condition[0]];
    let b = spaces[condition[1]];
    let c = spaces[condition[2]];
    if (a == undefined || b == undefined || c == undefined) {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

These were the few big problems you had that I saw on first glace, I think if you still have some problems, try to solve them yourself. I made an example tictactoe below, so if you are stuck, maybe try to look at the example for help (the code explains itself with comments):

```js
// container element where the rows and cells are going to be appended
const con = document.querySelector("#tictactoe")

// the current board
let cellsArr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];

// current player
let currentPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O";
let gameOver = false;

// conditions of winning, for both X and O
const winningConditions =
  [[0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]]


// reset function
// sets gameOver to true so players can't press buttons anymore
// resets the board (cellsArr array)
// adds a winningAlert to the DOM
// disables all buttons on the board
// resets DOM after 4 seconds
const reset = (tie) => {
  gameOver = true;
  cellsArr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
  const winningAlert = document.createElement("p");
  winningAlert.innerText = tie ? "Its a tie!" : `${currentPlayer} has won!`;
  con.appendChild(winningAlert);
  document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(e => e.disabled = true)
  setTimeout(() => {
    gameOver = false;
    init();
  }, 4000)
}

// check win function
// resarr -> maps through all the arrays of the winningConditions array and swaps the
//          indexes with the value of the board e.g: [1, 2, 3] => ["X", undefined, "O"]
// res -> find a array in winningConditions that has only 1 kind of element, 
//        but not undefined (Set is a data structure that only allows unique elements, so   
//        if the size of it is == 1 the array that was made of that set has only unique elements)
// if an array was found than res != undefined. If it is undefined, nothing happends, game is still on,
// else if it is undefined than reset the game, it is not a tie
// else if no array was found but all cells are already played, reset game, it is a tie
const checkWin = () => {
  const resarr = winningConditions.map(e => e.map(e => cellsArr[e]));
  const res = resarr.find(e => (new Set(e)).size == 1 && e.indexOf(undefined) == -1)
  if (res != undefined) {
    reset(false);
  } else if (cellsArr.indexOf(undefined) == -1) {
    reset(true);
  }
}

// initilizes the game
// creates a row with buttons, each 3 iterations create a new row so we have 3x3 board
// add an EventListener to each cell: 
// if gameOver or cell was already played, do nothing
// else set cell to currentPlayer, disable cell, check if won and switch player
function init() {
  let row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row"
  while (con.firstChild) con.firstChild.remove();
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("button");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      con.appendChild(row)
      row = document.createElement("div");
      row.className = "row"
    }

    cell.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (gameOver) return;
      if (cellsArr[i - 1] != undefined) return;
      cellsArr[i - 1] = currentPlayer;
      cell.innerText = currentPlayer;
      cell.disabled = true;
      checkWin();
      currentPlayer = currentPlayer == "X" ? "O" : "X"
    })
  }
}

init();
```

```css
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="tictactoe"></div>
```